More potent caffeine analogs (in silico study)
Is it possible to do a Structure Activity Relationship for caffeine given that its structure is similar to that of adenosine? Maybe more potent analogues can be made using caffeine as lead compound?
What could I do to conduct an in-silico study, say I make a new molecule (modified caffeine), in this case how would I test it for affinity for the adenosine receptors without going for in-vivo tests?

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1658821/ https://link.springer.com/article/10.2478/s11532-013-0389-y

Yes, it's totally possible to perform a Structure-Activity Relationship study for caffeine given its structural similarity to adenosine (see the comment left by Mithoron.) It would be quite iterative, but analogs could be synthesized by modifying caffeine's structure to potentially enhance its affinity or potency towards adenosine receptors. RDKit (open-source) can be used to identify caffeine derivatives with high affinity and selectivity for adenosine receptors.
Methylation and halogenation are two examples of modifications that can be explored to create new derivatives of caffeine1.
Identifying key structural features that aid in binding to adenosine receptors could be done in silico. You could use molecular docking software like AutoDock to dock your molecule into the binding site. Molecular dynamic simulations could aid in analyzing the interactions between the molecule and receptor over time.

Reference
Guo D, Heitman LH, IJzerman AP. Kinetic Aspects of the Interaction between Ligand and G Protein-Coupled Receptor: The Case of the Adenosine Receptors. Chem Rev. 2017 Jan 11;117(1):38-66. doi: 10.1021/acs.chemrev.6b00025. Epub 2016 Apr 18. PMID: 27088232.
Sidebar: You picked my favorite area of chemistry. Had I gone on to graduate school, I think this would have been my focus.
